# C code snippet dot operator syntax

Tags: c

I encountered the following code snippet within a cstartup file for a cortex m0 micro - `cstartup_M.c`

```
#pragma location = ".intvec"
__root const intvec_elem __vector_table[] =
{
  { .__ptr = __sfe( "CSTACK" ) },
  __iar_program_start,

  NonMaskableInt_Handler,
  HardFault_Handler,
```

Could someone please explain the syntax within the line: `{ .__ptr = __sfe( "CSTACK" ) },`

Specifically:

1. What is the purpose of the additional code block?
2. What is going on here:  `.__ptr`?

Comment: Could it be a designated initializer syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the new C99 initialization syntax. An initializer of the form

```
.field = value
```

initializes structure member `field` to `value` instead of initializing the next structure member in order.

Comment: well, that's embarrassing, I should have known that! An answer within 30 secs. Fair play!

Comment: @GregoryKuhn Happens to the best of us. Syntax is hard to search for.

Comment: "the new C99 initialization syntax"  It's 17 years old... :)

Comment: @Lundin Well, for Microsoft it's still new.